# Excel vba date filter and copy to new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use the VBA to filter the data according to the criteria: Date -3 to Date +3 and then copy to the new worksheet. If no result return, it also copy the blank to the new worksheet, but not success that only copy the today's data to the new worksheet, please tell me how to resolve this? Thank you very much.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton13_Click()
Dim d As Date
Dim wSheetStart As Worksheet
Set wSheetStart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ATA")

Sheets.Add.Name = "New report"
wSheetStart.Activate
wSheetStart.AutoFilterMode = False

For d = DateSerial(Year(Now - 3), Month(Now - 3), Day(Now - 3)) To DateSerial(Year(Now + 3), Month(Now + 3), Day(Now + 3))
ActiveSheet.Range("A6:AC6").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & d, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & d

Set rngVisible = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
If rngVisible.Rows.Count > 1 Or rngVisible.Areas.Count > 1 Then
Worksheets("ATA").Range("A7").Select
Worksheets("ATA").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Worksheets("ATA").Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
 Worksheets("New report").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
 Else
Worksheets("ATA").Range("A333:AC333").Select
 Selection.Copy
 Sheets("New report").Activate

 Sheets("New report").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial
End If

Next d
End Sub
```

Wanted result:
[image: A3 is the Worksheets("ATA").Range("A333:AC333") and A4 is the filtered data]

A3 is the Worksheets("ATA").Range("A333:AC333") and A4 is the filtered data

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* problem after trying to solve it on their own. If, after **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)**, you have a *specific* problem, please [edit] your post to share [examples of your code and relevant data](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some background info. Some good reading to get you started: "[ask]" as well as tips **[here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and **[here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 2):

As per your description, I don't think that you need to loop through date range. Instead, declare two date variables which may hold the start and end dates and filter the data accordingly.

Also, avoid selecting ranges and sheets unless really required.

Please give this a try and tweak it if required.

```
Private Sub CommandButton13_Click()
Dim dStart As Date, dEnd As Date
Dim wSheetStart As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim rngVisible As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wSheetStart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ATA")

dStart = DateAdd("d", -3, Date)
dEnd = DateAdd("d", 3, Date)

On Error Resume Next
Set wsDest = Sheets("New report")

If wsDest Is Nothing Then Sheets.Add.Name = "New report"

wSheetStart.AutoFilterMode = False

With wSheetStart
    .Range("A6:AC6").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & dStart, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & dEnd
    Set rngVisible = .AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If rngVisible.Rows.Count > 1 Or rngVisible.Areas.Count > 1 Then
        .Range("A7", .Range("A7").End(xlToRight).End(xlDown)).Copy wsDest.Range("A1")
    Else
        .Range("A333:AC333").Copy wsDest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
    End If
End With
wSheetStart.AutoFilterMode = False
wSheetStart.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean to include `Date + 3` in your `DateAdd` lines? Seems like you should use one (DateAdd)  or the other (Date+/-3)

Comment: @dbmitch Thanks for the catch. I forgot to remove that. :)

Comment: Nice answer - You should also let OP know that you've replaced the `.Select ` lines with better code

Comment: Thanks again! I was lazy to add that explanation. :)

Comment: When looking at OP's code I was wondering about the effect of the line that copies data from A7 down - wouldn't that copy all cells not just visible cells? Wouldn't it be better to copy the actual `rngVisible`? I haven't tested - just wondering?

Comment: I think he has something to copy from down the rows (Row#333) in case no data is returned by the autofilter. It's hard to say anything without looking at the data actually.

Comment: @sktneer thank you very much for your reply and let me know replaced the.select line. I tested the code. It is weird that need to run two time, then data were copied to new worksheet. Is it my excel problem?

Comment: @sktneer I want to copy the filtered data to new worksheet with specific format so I want to use the loop through the date range, here is my expected result: https://imgur.com/a/gAsRtwU